# Get instance-id of EC2 instance via Java

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ip, java

I have an AWS EC2 instance deployed as a server, and I need to find out its public IP. Howver, to know that I must first know the instance-id of my instance.

**Objective:**

- I have a Java code running in my instance, and I want that code figure out the current IP or Instance-ID of the instance where it is being run.

After reading Amazon documentation I came up with a Java method that returns the IP of all instances, **but this is not what I want**, I want a method that returns only the instance-id or the public IP address of the running instance.

```
    /**
     * Returns a list with the public IPs of all the active instances, which are
     * returned by the {@link #getActiveInstances()} method.
     * 
     * @return  a list with the public IPs of all the active instances.
     * @see     #getActiveInstances()
     * */
    public List<String> getPublicIPs(){
        List<String> publicIpsList = new LinkedList<String>();

        //if there are no active instances, we return immediately to avoid extra 
        //computations.
        if(!areAnyActive())
            return publicIpsList;

        DescribeInstancesRequest request =  new DescribeInstancesRequest();
        request.setInstanceIds(instanceIds);

        DescribeInstancesResult result = ec2.describeInstances(request);
        List<Reservation> reservations = result.getReservations();

        List<Instance> instances;
        for(Reservation res : reservations){
            instances = res.getInstances();
            for(Instance ins : instances){
                LOG.info("PublicIP from " + ins.getImageId() + " is " + ins.getPublicIpAddress());
                publicIpsList.add(ins.getPublicIpAddress());
            }
        }

        return publicIpsList;
    }
```

In this code I have an array with the instance-ids of all active instances, but I do not know if they are "me" or not. So I assume that my first step would be to know who I am, and then to ask for my public IP address.

Is there a change I can do to the previous method to give me what I want? Is there a more efficient way of doing it?

---

**EDIT**

Really? Can someone explain me how a question about a virtualized server, in this case an EC2 AWS instance is off-topic when inside a forum to ask questions about servers?

This fully complies with the following two points of the rules:

- Server and Workstation operating systems, hardware, and software;
- Business/Enterprise grade virtualization.

Furthermore, there are **plenty** of questions about EC2 in this forum (even ones asking for programming answers) and the fact that someone actually answered my question proves my point - this is the right place to ask it.

I'm leaving this comment as a disapproval of your actions, **it is people like you who drive new users away**. I know I marked this as answered, but I am still doing it. Why? Because it is the principle that counts.

Comment: This seems more like a programming question, which is off-Topic on serverfault. You might want to try StackOverflow.com

Comment: This is very plainly a programming question and should have been posted on [so]. You were not asking about administering the _server_ at all. Since you did cross-post it there already, I am not migrating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the instance metadata documented here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html

below I wrote a simple piece of java code which prints the running instance-id

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Scanner;

public final class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL("http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id");
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    Scanner s = new Scanner(conn.getInputStream());
    if (s.hasNext()) {
      System.out.println(s.next());
    } 
  }
}
```

The code must be executed from a running ec2 instance